# Creating a function to return available teachers with a date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have a SQL function that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_available_teachers ()
RETURNS TABLE (teacherid INT, firstname text, lastname text) 
AS $func$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT DISTINCT t.teacherid, t.firstname, t.lastname
        FROM classes c
        JOIN teacher_teacherteam tt ON tt.teacherteamid = c.teacherteamid
        JOIN teachers t ON t.teacherid = tt.teacherid
        --WHERE c.starts > NOW();
        WHERE c.starts > '2000-01-01' AND c.ends < '2010-01-01';
end; $func$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I have commented out the where clause, to get it to return the classes from the teachers that are available as of now.

So now when I run the function like this:

```
SELECT find_available_teachers()
```

it just returns one empty table, why is it, that i can't seem to get anything out of the tables

Below i have listed all the data from the respective tables:

```
0   0   "2020-02-25 20:31:30.463451"    "2020-03-26 20:31:30.463451"    0   "Attendance"
1   1   "2020-02-25 20:33:09.336577"    "2020-03-26 20:33:09.336577"    0   "Online"
2   4   "2020-02-25 20:47:04.939029"    "2020-03-26 20:47:04.939029"    0   "Attendance"
3   1   "2020-02-25 20:47:12.139878"    "2020-03-26 20:47:12.139878"    0   "Attendance"
4   2   "2020-02-25 20:47:18.468703"    "2020-03-26 20:47:18.468703"    0   "Attendance"
10  1   "2020-02-24 21:00:34.229316"    "2020-01-26 21:00:34.229316"    2   "Attendance"
11  1   "2020-02-24 21:30:37.319799"    "2020-01-26 21:30:37.319799"    2   "Attendance"
12  1   "2020-02-15 21:30:49.223645"    "2020-01-26 21:30:49.223645"    2   "Attendance"
13  1   "1992-02-29 21:30:55.872471"    "2020-01-26 21:30:55.872471"    2   "Attendance"
14  1   "2019-11-15 21:31:11.786364"    "2020-01-26 21:31:11.786364"    2   "Attendance"
```

Comment: What are the columns for the sample data?

Comment: For one, you should use that function in the FROM clause: `select * from find_available_teachers()`

Comment: Does the query return anything when run outside the function?  And why not use a view instead of a function?